# Display a comment based on the user name in the PHP login?

Tags: php

I have a PHP Login using a flat file (.txt) system with a username and password this is in a file called users.txt and they are in the following layout e.g.

User1||Password1

User2||Password2

User3||Password3

Till now I managed to get users to login based on their username and paswords.

Now I would like a PHP code so that when users login using the above method, a custom comment is displayed based on the username. I would like this in a separate text file, and to be displayed according to how the user logged in e.g.

User1||Hello John, you look great

User2||Don't let the rain spoil your day

User3||Hooray for holidays

So if User1 logs in using his username and password - only they can see their associated comment, and the same for the others.

How can this be done please?

I was thinking of having a code similar to this

```
$name = $_SESSION["valid_user"]; 
$comments = $_POST['comments']; 
$file = file_get_contents("comments.txt"); 
if(strstr($file, "$name||$comments"))
```

Comment: What do you have so far? And I do hope you are salting and hashing the passwords...

Comment: By the way, you'd better use a database for this.

Comment: I know but i prefer using a textfile for the time being.

Comment: Care to share your login script in this kind of approach.

Comment: I got it from the following website - http://www.kirupa.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-281825.html

Answer (score 0):

Umm.. I don't think you understand PHP/Login.

Passwords + Text files = Horrible. You should store the information in a database, like MySql.

Then, you can do a simple if statement/switch command to output a custom message for each user.

```
if($username == 'Alan') { echo "Welcome boss"; }
else if($username == 'Clara') { echo "you look great today"; }
else { echo "Welcome ".$username; }
```

Comment: Hi AlanPHP, I want something on those lines you're mentioning but I would like the site to get the comments from a text file instead of being on the page e.g. a file called comments.txt

so for 
User1||Hello John, you look great

User2||Don't let the rain spoil your day

User3||Hooray for holidays

Comment: Maybe a code similar to this 


$name = $_SESSION["valid_user"];
 $comments = $_POST['comments'];
 $file = file_get_contents("comments.txt");
 if(strstr($file, "$name||$comments"))

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is just make an array where the keys are the user names and the values are the comments for each user.

```
$comments = array(
  "user1" => "You smell funny.",
  "user2" => "Your cat is annoying me.",
  "user3" => "You're an okay person... for now.",
  // So on and so on...
);
```

Not that I condone the way you're doing your login or content storage.

Comment: $name = $_SESSION["valid_user"]; 
$comments = $_POST['comments']; 
$file = file_get_contents("comments.txt"); 
if(strstr($file, "$name||$comments"))